# "Error: Allowed memory size issue"

Tags: 7, drush

I have Drush installed on my Inmotion hosting server.
For one Drupal 7 site, it works just fine but for the other one, which is nearly identical, it doesn't work so well.
Some commands it allows (like my favourite `drush sql-dump` or `drush cc` followed by 5) and but when I do a command `drush cc all` it throws an out-of-memory issue as shown below:

```
Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.                                                                         [error]
Error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in
/home/myAccount/public_html/mysite.net/sites/all/modules/views/includes/base.inc, line 129
```

The issues stemming from the base.inc file are:

after command: `drush cc all`: on line 129:
`$storage[$option] = isset($definition['default']) ? $definition['default'] : NULL;`

The issues stemming from the view.inc file are:

after command: `drush cc all`: on line 2244:
`$this->$field = unserialize($info['serialized default']);`

after command: `drush cc all`: on line 2312:
`$this->$field = empty($info['serialize']) ? $data->$field : unserialize($data->$field);`

The php.ini files are identical on both sites.
The settings.php files are not identical and I thought it would be resolved by adding the same lines to the ending of the file

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$conf['error_level'] = 2;
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
```

but this didn't solve the problem (even after clearing the cache).

What could cause this problem?

Comment: Try to increase your memory_limit to 1G or -1 if you don't want a memory_limit

Comment: Thank you so much! 
I've changed it to 1G and it didn't throw any errors anymore. 
I read somewhere that the option -1 as memory_limit is not advisable, is that correct?

Comment: Interesting: if the `ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');` is not set in the setting.php file, it will still throw an error. If it is set, the error is gone.

Comment: I don't have the knowledge to answer your question about the -1 value. All I can say is I never had problems with it on a dev machine. But is it advisable for a production server ? I don't know, I am sorry.

Comment: I appreciate your help and honesty, MacSim